# Cant get orbit controls working in static three.js scene

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I have a static three.js scene where Im experimenting with lighting on a `PlaneBufferGeometry`, however I would also like to use `OrbitControls` to pan scene's camera around to check it out from different angles.

However, I have no idea why `OrbitControls` isn't working, can someone explain?

Bonus: why is the scene being stretched out on browser resize? Doesn't the resize handler handle the camera aspect ratio already?

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import * as THREE from "three"
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"

const Canvas = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let container, scene, axes, camera, controls, renderer

    const init = () => {
      container = document.querySelector(".canvas-container")

      scene = new THREE.Scene()
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x181818)
      axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(2)
      scene.add(axes)

      const fov = 60
      const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight
      const near = 0.1
      const far = 1000
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far)
      camera.position.set(-3, 1, 5)
      camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

      const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xf2abd6, 1, 100)
      const helper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(light, 1)
      light.position.set(0, 0, 2.5)
      scene.add(light)
      scene.add(helper)

      const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(3, 3, 1, 1)
      const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        wireframe: false,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
      })
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
      scene.add(mesh)

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
      renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight)
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

      // FIX: orbit controls dragging with mouse not working
      controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
      controls.addEventListener("change", render)
      controls.update()
      controls.enableDamping = true
      controls.dampingFactor = 0.2

      window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false)
    }

    const resize = () => {
      camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
      renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight)
    }

    const render = () => renderer.render(scene, camera)

    init()
    render()

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", resize)
  }, [])

  return <div className="canvas-container" />
}

export default Canvas
```

Also, the codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/canvas-lighting-experiment-wip-3p9im?file=/src/Canvas.component.jsx

Comment: Turns out it was css... I had set `pointer-events: none`, removing it and it worked

Comment: Consider to post this comment as an answer instead ;)